# Styling em menus

Tags: html, css, menu

Estou a criar um menu para um site de classificados, e queria colocar uma borda arredondada(border-radius) no item 'publicar anuncio', usando css.

Deixo aqui o meu código do menu:

```
    <nav class="menu" id="menu">
<img src="images/site.jpg" width="200px">

<a href="publicar" class="pub">Publicar anúncio</a>

<a href="login" class="regi">Login</a>

<a href="registo" class="log">Registar</a>

<a href="categorias">Categorias</a>

<a href="blog">Blog da equipa</a>

<a href="#">Home</a>

<a href="" class="icon" id="icon">

<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

</a>

</nav>
```

Enfim, não consigo identificar o item 'publicar anuncio' no css.

Comment: E qual é a dificuldade?

Comment: já olhaste alguma documentação? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para se referir ao item `publicar anuncio` no css, você deve fazer desta forma:

```css
.pub {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Neste exemplo, você deixaria uma borda preta, de `1px`, com 100% de `radius`, em todas as tags que possuírem a propriedade `class="pub"`.

> Mais sobre `border`:
>
> [Border CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Brother vc ja tem uma classe "pub" com ela vc consegue identifica-lo no CSS!

```css
.pub {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: .9em;
  transition: all ease-in-out .4s;
}

.pub:hover {
  color: #333;
  background: #FFF
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <a href="publicar" class="pub">Publicar anúncio</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.pub{
border: 1px black solid;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```